# Showing a Frame is Orthonormal

Tags: differential-geometry

I know this is really simple. But I don't know how to carry out the calculation, I can only "see" why the following is a orthonormal frame.

Let

$$E_1 = \frac{x}{r}\frac{\partial }{\partial x} + \frac{y}{r}\frac{\partial }{\partial y}$$

$$E_2=-\frac{y}{r}\frac{\partial }{\partial x} + \frac{x}{r}\frac{\partial }{\partial y}$$

Naturally, these are radial lines and circles respectively... but how do I "do" the simple calculation $E_i*E_j=\delta_{ij}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is a vector field on $\Bbb R^2$ with the standard metric (the dot product) and $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$, we have that
$$\langle E_1, E_1 \rangle = \frac{x^2}{r^2} + \frac{y^2}{r^2} = \frac{x^2 + y^2}{r^2} = \frac{r^2}{r^2} = 1,$$
$$\langle E_2, E_2 \rangle = \frac{y^2}{r^2} + \frac{x^2}{r^2} = \frac{x^2 + y^2}{r^2} = \frac{r^2}{r^2} = 1,$$
and
$$\langle E_1, E_2 \rangle = -\frac{xy}{r^2} + \frac{xy}{r^2} = 0.$$

The above calculations are done by just realizing that $\displaystyle \left\{ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right\}$ is just the standard basis for $\Bbb R^2$ and then applying the definition of the standard dot product. This just means
$$\left\langle \frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \right\rangle = 1,$$
$$\left\langle \frac{\partial}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right\rangle = 1,$$
and
$$\left\langle \frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right\rangle = 0.$$
Note that what I wrote above assumes you are using the standard inner product on $\Bbb R^2$.

Note that since these are vector fields, we have the check that $\langle E_i(x,y), E_j(x,y) \rangle = \delta_{ij}$ for all points $(x, y) \in \Bbb R^2$. But $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$ for all $(x, y) \in \Bbb R^2$ so everything done above is fine.

Comment: Thank you. I also got this.... except I'm not sure where the partial derivatives enter this.  That's my primary confusion.  Could you include that in your calculation, that would help me out a lot! Thanks, again.

Comment: Your most recent edit which includes that the partials form a standard basis is also known to me.... well its really the basis for the dual of R^2 (isomorphic to R^2).  But can you explicitly include it in the calculation.

Comment: For this question the partial derivatives don't enter at all. The partial notation is due to the fact that a vector field can be seen as a directional derivative operator: If we have a function $f: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ and a vector field $V = a(x,y) \tfrac{\partial}{\partial x} + b(x,y) \tfrac{\partial}{\partial y}$, then $$Vf(x_0,y_0) = a(x_0,y_0) \tfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0) + b(x_0,y_0) \tfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)$$ is the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction of $V$ at the point $(x_0,y_0)$.

Comment: Thank you for your edits which specifically addressed my comments!! This made a lot of sense as soon as I remembered the basis for $\mathbb{R}^{2*}$.

Comment: By the way, $\{\tfrac{\partial}{\partial x}, \tfrac{\partial}{\partial y}\}$ _is_ a basis for $\Bbb R^2$. The dual basis is denoted by $\{dx, dy\}$.